# How display a form button with JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I follow this course to build my multistep form inside a blade view for Laravel: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps

I want to display the next button only if the checkbox input on this current view is checked but it's not working for me.

This is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('stagiaire.theorique.test.store_seul',['id'=>$eval->id]) }}" id="questionform" name="examForm">
    @csrf

    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
    </div>

    @foreach($questioncat as $key => $category)
                @foreach($category->getQuestion as $question)
                    <fieldset class="theorique-body" id="categorie_{{ $key }}">

                        <div class="header-question" id="q{{ $question->id}}">
                            <h2 class="nomcat">{{ $category->nom }}</h2>
                            <h3 class="question">{{ $question->question_text }}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body-question">
                            <div class="image">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $question->image) }}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="reponsebouton">
                            <input type="hidden" name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]" value="">
                                <p>Merci de choisir votre réponse</p>
                                @foreach($question->reponse as $option)

                                <div class="button-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]" id="option-{{ $option->id }}" value="{{ $option->id }}"@if(old("questions.$question->id") == $option->id) checked @endif>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="option-{{ $option->id }}">
                                            {{ $option->option_text }}
                                        </label>
                                </div>
                                @endforeach

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>


                        @if($errors->has("questions.$question->id"))
                        <p class="font-bold">Attention :</p>
                                <span style="margin-top: .25rem; font-size: 80%; color: #e3342f;" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first("questions.$question->id") }}</strong>
                                </span>
                        @endif

                @endforeach
    @endforeach
    <div style="overflow:auto;" id="butform">
        <div style="float:right;">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
            <button class="text-white bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-600 to-blue-500 hover:bg-gradient-to-bl focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:focus:ring-blue-800 rounded-lg text-m px-5 py-4 font-bold uppercase text-center mr-2 mb-2" type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Suivant</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("theorique-body");
    var y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Terminer le test";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Suivant";
    }
    //affiche le bouton en cas de reponse


    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("theorique-body");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("questionform").submit();
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("theorique-body");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");

    // // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    // for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    //     // If a field is empty...
    //     if (y[i].value == "") {
    //       // add an "invalid" class to the field:
    //       y[i].className += " invalid";
    //       // and set the current valid status to false
    //       valid = false;
    //     }
    //   }

    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: `if the checkbox input on this current view` What's the form? I don't see any checkbox

Comment: Please add your `html` code as well

Comment: @DreamBold Hello, I edit my post with my form. Thanks

Comment: `@if(old("questions.$question->id") == $option->id)` Not sure what this part is for,

Comment: It's for remind the old selection of user. So how do you think I can do?

Comment: `if($question->id == $option->id) checked @endif>` It should be like this?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I just want to display the next button when one of the two options is checked on the currentTab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249882/discussion-between-dream-bold-and-chrisdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just need to check if one of the questions has been checked, you can implement the code like this:

```
 function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, z, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  
  z = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  if (z.length < 1) {
        valid = false;
  } else{
        valid = true;
  }
  
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

The full code is below:

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, z, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  
  z = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  if (z.length < 1) {
        valid = false;
  } else{
        valid = true;
  }
  
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

input[type="radio"]{
    width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input type="radio" name="fname">First Question</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="lname">Second Question</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input type="radio" name="fname">Third Question</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="lname">Fourth Question</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok now I understand, very thank you for your help !